# How to internationalize a converter or renderer in Wicket?

Tags: localization, internationalization, wicket, translation

I'm translating a web application and things are generally going smoothly with wicket:message and properties files. But Wicket always wants to have a component for looking up strings.
How can I translate converters and renderers (i.e. implementations of `IConverter` and `IChoiceRenderer`) which don't have access to any Wicket component in their methods?

So far I found one way - `Application.get().getResourceSettings().getLocalizer().getString(key, null)` - but I have to make the strings "global", i.e. associated with the application class. That's not nice for separation and reuse. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found another way...

I noticed that `IStringResourceLoader` also has a method `String loadStringResource(Class<?> clazz, String key, Locale locale, String style);` (and one more parameter for variation in newer Wicket versions) which does not require a component. `clazz` is supposed to be a component class, but... it doesn't actually **have to** be :)

I was able to implement my own `class MyLocalizer extends Localizer` with a new method
`getString(String key, Class<?> cl, IModel<?> model, Locale locale, String defaultValue)`
which works in a similar way to
`getString(String key, Component component, IModel<?> model, String defaultValue)`
but uses the class directly instead of a component. It still uses the same properties cache and resource loaders.

Then I wrote an `abstract class MyConverter implements IConverter` which has a `MyLocalizer getLocalizer()` and a few `getString` methods like the `Component` class. Basically it does `getLocalizer().getString(key, getClass(), model, locale, defaultValue)`, so the properties can now be attached to the converter class.

Seems to work :)

Comment: Interesting way. I was thinking about it too, but it seems awkward as you have to cast localizer each time or you have to introduce something like you do with MyConverter. Anyway it doesn't look so bad in the end....

Answer (score 2):

I think you should invent you own way how to achieve this. Here in my current project we registered our own IStringResourceLoader like this:

```
IStringResourceLoader stringResourceLoader = new OurOwnResourceLoaderImpl();               
Application.get().getResourceSettings().getStringResourceLoaders().add(stringResourceLoader);
```

Then for example in IChoiceRenderer we just call Application.get().getLocalizer().getString("key", null).

Inside our IStringResourceLoader we are looking for bundles (property files) with some string pattern according our own conventions.

Or you can just register localization bundle (ie. properties file) distributed inside your library's jar in Application#init through org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.BundleStringResourceLoader.

Afaik there is no standard way to do that so it's up to you what path you choose.

**Updated:**

I found another solution how your library/extension can register it's own localization by itself so you needn't to touch Application#init or create your own IStringResourceLoaders.

There is preregistered string resource loader org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.InitializerStringResourceLoader (see wickets default IResourceSetting implementation ie. ResourceSetting and it's constructor)  which uses wicket's Initializer mechanism - see IInitializer javadoc - basically you add wicket.properties file in your jar class root (ie. it is in default/none package) and inside file there is:

```
initializer=i.am.robot.MyInitilizer
```

then i.am.robot.MyInitilizer:

```
public class MyInitializer implements IInitializer {

    /**
     * @param application
     *            The application loading the component
     */
    void init(Application application) {
        // do whatever want
    }

    /**
     * @param application
     *            The application loading the component
     */
     void destroy(Application application) {

     }

}
```

and now you create your localization bundles in same package and same name as IInitializer implementation (in our example MyInitializer)

Comment: Well, this way the properties files are still registered globally right? They can be in different files, but still associated with the whole web application.

Comment: Well it depends what way you will use. When you call Localizer#getString(...) then it's trying to ask each registered IStringResourceLoader if there is localized text for that localization key. If you will use org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.BundleStringResourceLoader than yes, it will be registered same way as your application localization file.

Comment: Yes, well, if I call `getString(key, null)` then I think it's going to be global, as there's nothing specific (such as a class) to attach to. But I found a different solution, check the answer I just posted. The IInitializer thing is quite interesting, I think I can combine the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question...

You can use package based properties that means if you put your keys/values into a property file 'package.properties' in a package. Each localized resource of any subpackage under that package returns the value associated to the requested key until you override it in another property file.

The file name is '**package.properties**' in Wicket prior to 1.6.x and '**wicket-package.properties**' in Wicket 1.6+

See

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+6.0#MigrationtoWicket6.0-package.propertiesrenamedtowicket-package.properties

However it works just for componet, outside the componet (when component argument is null), it is possible to use:

**WicketApplication.properties** (the WebApplication class is **WicketApplication.class**, this property file is in the same package).

```
applicationGlobalProperty=My Global Localized Property
```

**wicket-package.properties** (package based, place it in the same package as the page)

```
localText=Localized text: A local component text based on wicket-package.properties
```

**LocalizedPage.html** (markup template)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Localized Page</title>
</head>
<body xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

<div>
    <div>

        <h2>Texts</h2>
            <div>
                <wicket:message key="localText"/> <br/>
                <span wicket:id="localizedLabel"></span>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**LocalizePage.java** (code)

```
public class LocalizedPage extends WebPage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LocalizedPage() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();

        add(new Label("localizedLabel", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String getObject() {
                return WicketApplication.get().getResourceSettings().getLocalizer().getString("applicationGlobalProperty", null);
            }
        }));

    }

}
```

See the full example on https://repo.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-6.x/browse

Comment: Afaik this won't work with Application.get().getResourceSettings().getLocalizer().getString(key, null). It works with packages in hierarchy starting with package where component is and then climbing up to parent packages. Ie. it have to know when to start looking up in hierarchy of packages, but when you tell that component is null it won't.

Comment: Well, how would I get the string from the package based properties?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is not possible to use getString(key, null). In this case the global property file is in a property file named after the application class e.g. WicketApplication, I made a small example on https://repo.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-6.x/browse

Comment: Look at LocalizedPage that uses <wicket:message key="globalHomeLink"/> and <wicket:message key="localText"/> in markup (it uses property itself), than label 'localizedLabel' invokes WicketApplication.get().getResourceSettings().getLocalizer().getString("applicationGlobalProperty", null); in code.

Comment: I can't find any LocalizedPage

Comment: Sorry, something is broken in the git, I'm going to fix it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47947/discussion-between-martin-strejc-and-aditsu)